# How to import the sikuli module in python?

Tags: python, sikuli

I'm having trouble getting sikuli+python unit testing to work, and would be glad for some assistance.
I searched the internet far and wide, but haven't anything that worked. My python knowledge is very limited, and I guess that doesn't help...

I'm using win7 32,
sikuli 1.0 rc3 (r905),
python 2.7.3

I'm trying to start running sikuli unit tests through python (not with command line, just as a python script to run with the python gui). I've followed, among others, the instructions shown here: http://sikuli.org/docx/globals.html
and here: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1804

my sikuli script (name: **slidelyChromeUnitTest2.sikuli**) starts like this (the rest doesn't matter becuase it gets stuck on the very first line):

```
from sikuli import *
import unittest
```

and my python script (name: **SikuliTestRunner.py**)  looks like this:

```
import sys

mySikuliPath = "D:\\Program Files\\Sikuli X\\slidelyChromeUnitTest2.sikuli"
if not mySikuliPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(mySikuliPath)

import slidelyChromeUnitTest2
```

And what I get when I run the python script is this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Python27\SikuliTestRunner.py", line 6, in 
>       import slidelyChromeUnitTest2   File "D:\Program Files\Sikuli X\slidelyChromeUnitTest2.sikuli\slidelyChromeUnitTest2.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from sikuli import * ImportError: No module named sikuli

And I can't get past that error...
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Ilan

Comment: do you need a `from sikuli.Sikuli import *`. I remember doing this, but haven't touched sikuli since i left my old company. I remember it being buggy and a pain...but useful

Comment: Still waiting on the "useful" part :) Thanks for your answer, but I get exactly the same problem with sikuli.Sikuli. It's just that now python complains about "sikuli.Sikuli" not being a module instead of just about "sikuli"

Comment: check out: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/136170

Answer (score 5):

It's Jython you can't.
http://doc.sikuli.org/devs/system-design.html

edit: updated the link, removed a dead post reference.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. My use of python was indeed the problem.