# Run Sikuli files from another sikuli project

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

What I want to do is to have several UnitTests written in sikuli, in different files, and then generate a report.

I would want to do something like this:

Project Tests_Thing1.sikuli:

```
import unittest

class Tests_Thing1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #do some stuff     
    def tearDown(self):
        #do some stuff  
    def test_Created(self):
        #do some sikuli stuff
```

And there are similar Similar Tests_Thing2 and Tests_Thing3 projects

Project Run_Tests.sikuli:

```
import unittest
## import siluli projects?

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTests(Tests_Thing1)
suite.addTests(Tests_Thing2)
suite.addTests(Tests_Thing3)

suite.run(result)
#generate report from all tests
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the standard unittest http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/TestingIntegration.html and import Sikuli into your classes. You need Jython to run it as the following

[How to import the sikuli module in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583682/how-to-import-the-sikuli-module-in-python)

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/136170

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to have the same thing. I wanted to run several tests and create a report.
What I did was created a simple application which ran the selected sikuli scripts one by one on the command line. I collected their output (pass, fail, error messages) in a text file and displayed it again in the app. One can actually write an Html or something.

e.g.
runsikulix.cmd -r TableSelectCells.sikuli >> report.txt

Here you can check more how to do it from the command line.
http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html